# How do I read the SEP citations for a particular author where there are numbers at the end of the sentence as a citation?

Tags: descartes

How do I read the SEP citations for a particular author where there are numbers at the end of the sentence as a citation?

An example from the [SEP article on Descartes](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/#HowDoOurMinKno):

> "Descartes had a different account. He held that the eternal truths are the free creations of God (1:145, 149, 151; 7:380, 432)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See :

> [**Note on references and abbreviations**](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/#Bib): References to Descartes' works as found herein use the pagination of the Adam and Tannery volumes (AT), *Oeuvres de Descartes*, 11 vols. The citations give volume and page numbers only (dropping the abbreviation “AT”). Where possible, the Cottingham, Stoothoff, Murdoch, and Kenny translation, *The Philosophical Writings of Descartes*, 3 vols., has been used; it shows the AT pagination in the margins. Where the translation has been emended, the citation is marked with an asterisk (*). The AT volume numbers provide a guide to which work is being cited in translation: vols. 1–5, correspondence; vol. 6, *Discourse* and essays (including the *Dioptrics* and *Meteorology*); vol. 7, *Meditations*; vol. 10, *Rules*; vol. 11:1–118, *World*, or *Treatise on Light*; vol. 11:119–222, *Treatise on Man*; vol. 11:301–488, *Passions*. Where there is no accessible translation for a citation from AT, the citation is shown in italics. Works that are broken into parts and/or articles are cited by abbreviated title, part, and article: Med. for the Meditations, Met. for the Meteorology, Princ. for the Principles, and Pass. for the Passions.